# Animation to translate right arrow

Tags: css, css-animations

I would like to animate a "right-arrow" with a translation from left to right. Or, as my arrow is created using the "transform" properties, my animation applies to both transforms (rotate and translate) ...

In my example below, the arrow is translated AND rotated by the animation. I would like it to be only translated. How could I do that ?

```css
i {
    border: solid black;
    border-width: 0 3px 3px 0;
    display: inline-block;
    padding: 3px;
}

.right {
    transform: rotate(-45deg);
    -webkit-transform: rotate(-45deg);
    transition: transform 400ms ease !important;
}

.link-page-1 p {
            cursor:pointer;
}

.link-page-1:hover p {
    color: #727272 !important;

}

.link-page-1:hover .right  {
    transform: rotate(-45deg);
transform: translate(10px,0px);

}
```

```html
<p class="link-page-1" style="font-size:20px; color:black;">En savoir plus  <i class="arrow right"></i></p>
```

Thanks for your help !

Comment: Please explain, quite unclear question...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Right now you have multiple `transforms`, which causes only the last one(`translate`) to take effect, as well as defaulting the `rotate` back to `0`. What you need to do is combine `rotate` and `translate` into a single `transform`:

```css
i {
    border: solid black;
    border-width: 0 3px 3px 0;
    display: inline-block;
    padding: 3px;
}

.right {
    transform: rotate(-45deg);
    -webkit-transform: rotate(-45deg);
    transition: transform 400ms ease !important;
}

.link-page-1 p {
            cursor:pointer;
}

.link-page-1:hover p {
    color: #727272 !important;

}

.link-page-1:hover .right  {
    transform:rotate(-45deg) translate(10px,0px);
    -webkit-transform:rotate(-45deg) translate(10px,0px);
}
```

```html
<p class="link-page-1" style="font-size:20px; color:black;">En savoir plus  <i class="arrow right"></i></p>
```

Comment: Thanks for your quick answer :)

Comment: No problem at all

Answer (score 0):

Please refer to the following code, You need to combine both translate and rotate with space separated properties.
I hope this is what you are looking for.

```css
i {
    border: solid black;
    border-width: 0 3px 3px 0;
    display: inline-block;
    padding: 3px;
}

.right {
    transform: rotate(-45deg);
    -webkit-transform: rotate(-45deg);
    transition: transform 400ms ease !important;
}

.link-page-1 p {
            cursor:pointer;
}

.link-page-1:hover p {
    color: #727272 !important;

}

.link-page-1:hover .right  {
    
transform: translate(10px) rotate(-45deg);

}
```

```html
<p class="link-page-1" style="font-size:20px; color:black;">En savoir plus  <i class="arrow right"></i></p>
```